# Problemas com estrutura HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css

Estou com um caso em que não consigo resolver, estou desenvolvendo um layout em HTML e CSS onde uso flexbox centralizando o conteúdo, bem, em telas grandes funciona tudo ok, mas em tela pequenas a `div` estoura e não mostra o conteúdo que deveria mostrar.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #333;
    
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
 background: #e9e9e9;
 overflow: hidden;
}
div.content {
    height: calc(100vh - 70px);
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
div.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 35px;
    background-color: #FF4500;
}
/*div.container-menu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 750px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}*/
div.menu {
    height: auto;
    width: 750px;    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div.item-menu-busca {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    background: #FF4500;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.item-menu {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
div.item-menu:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    background: #FF4500;    
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
svg.ico-busca {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    fill: #FFF;
}
svg.ico {
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    fill: #FF4500;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
div.item-menu:hover > svg.ico {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    fill: #FFF;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.md-modal {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 50%;
 max-width: 630px;
 min-width: 320px;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 2000;
 visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.md-show {
 visibility: visible;
}
.md-overlay {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 visibility: hidden;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 opacity: 0;
 background: rgba(143,27,15,0.8);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-show ~ .md-overlay {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}
/* Content styles */
.md-content {
 color: #fff;
 background: #e74c3c;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.md-content h3 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0.4em;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2.4em;
 font-weight: 300;
 opacity: 0.8;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.md-content > div {
 padding: 15px 40px 30px;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 1.15em;
}

.md-content > div p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 0;
}

.md-content > div ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 30px 20px;
}

.md-content > div ul li {
 padding: 5px 0;
}

.md-content button {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}

/* Effect 12:  Just me */
.md-effect-12 .md-content {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
 -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-show.md-effect-12 ~ .md-overlay {
 background: #e74c3c;
} 

.md-effect-12 .md-content h3,
.md-effect-12 .md-content {
 background: transparent;
}

.md-show.md-effect-12 .md-content {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
 opacity: 1;
}
button {
 border: none;
 padding: 0.6em 1.2em;
 background: #c0392b;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 3px 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

button:hover {
 background: #A5281B;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>VIPAGIS - Convergência</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="md-modal md-effect-12" id="modal-12">
   <div class="md-content">
    <h3>Modal Dialog</h3>
    <div>
     <p>This is a modal window. You can do the following things with it:</p>
     <ul>
      <li><strong>Read:</strong> modal windows will probably tell you something important so don't forget to read what they say.</li>
      <li><strong>Look:</strong> a modal window enjoys a certain kind of attention; just look at it and appreciate its presence.</li>
      <li><strong>Close:</strong> click on the button below to close the modal.</li>
     </ul>
     <button class="md-close">Close me!</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
        <div class="md-overlay"></div><!-- the overlay element -->
        <div class="content">
                <!-- <div class="container-menu"> -->
                    <div class="menu">
                        <div class="item-menu-busca" id="bt1">
                            <svg class="ico-busca">
                                <use xlink:href="css/suporte/icones.svg#ico-busca"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-menu">
                            <svg class="ico">
                                <use xlink:href="css/suporte/icones.svg#ico-home"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-menu">
                            <svg class="ico">
                                <use xlink:href="css/suporte/icones.svg#ico-email"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-menu">
                            <svg class="ico">
                                <use xlink:href="css/suporte/icones.svg#ico-login"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-menu">
                            <svg class="ico">
                                <use xlink:href="css/suporte/icones.svg#ico-compartilha"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-menu">
                            <svg class="ico">
                                <use xlink:href="css/suporte/icones.svg#ico-download"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-menu">
                            <svg class="ico">
                                <use xlink:href="css/suporte/icones.svg#ico-sair"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-menu">
                            <svg class="ico">
                                <use xlink:href="css/suporte/icones.svg#ico-clip"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-menu">
                            <svg class="ico" height="60px" width="60px">
                                <use xlink:href="css/suporte/icones.svg#ico-2"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-menu"></div>
                        <div class="item-menu"></div>
                        <div class="item-menu"></div>
                        <div class="item-menu"></div>
                        <div class="item-menu"></div>
                        <div class="item-menu"></div>
                        <div class="item-menu"></div>
                    </div>
                <!--</div>-->
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Executem o código no navegador e renderizem pr uma tela menor e os quadradinhos não aparecerão corretamente, preciso de ajuda.

Comment: Você conhece media queries?

Comment: Conheço mas ainda nao sei como isso pode resolver meu problema

Comment: Com elas você deixa sua div responsiva, olha esse link http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Diego para mim está aparecendo normal, o que exatamente não está de acordo ? Estou usando o chrome e ele tá se comportando bem... O que exatamente há de errado...

Comment: Magichat, estou tendo dificuldades em fazer meu layout se comportar bem quando redimensiono no navegador pra um tamanho menor, essas 16 div do centro deveria todas aparecer mas quando o navegador esta pequeno 3 delas não aparecem por causa do flexbox centralizado, este é o meu problema

Answer (score 0):

Via css você pode controlar os break-points, uma dica é usar porcentagem em vez de pixel na div, segue exemplo:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  div.item-menu { 
      width: 33%;  
  }
}
```

Comment: obrigado, vou usar sua dica